# I cannot get Steemit posts from the steem API by any other category other than trending new and hot

Tags: javascript, api, steemit

So I tried to get steemit posts with the official API. The API provides many ways to fetch the posts but I just get an error all the time. I can use the main method

```
steem.api.getDiscussionsByCreated({tag: "sampletag", limit: 10}, function(a, b) {console.log(a, b)})
```

And this method indeed returns posts that I want, however, I try similar methods ALSO in the API

```
steem.api.getDiscussionsByPayout({tag: "sampletag", limit: 10}, function(a, b) {console.log(a, b)})
```

And I get errors like:

```
Error: Assert Exception:method_itr != api_itr->second.end(): Could not find method get_discussions_by_payout
```

Now I am very confused why one works and one doesn't, maybe someone can help and provide me with a guide on how to use all these methods as clearly I am doing something wrong. Maybe some sort of documentation of some sort (the one on GitHub doesn't explain it clearly, it just says query in place of the json object)?

Answer (score 0):

`getDiscussionsByPayout` has been split into two functions: [`getPostDiscussionsByPayout`](https://developers.steem.io/apidefinitions/#tags_api.get_post_discussions_by_payout) and [`getCommentDiscussionsByPayout`](https://developers.steem.io/apidefinitions/#tags_api.get_comment_discussions_by_payout).

Though, I still get `Object {error: Object {code: -32000, …}}` returned from that.

Comment: that was just an example, there are many more that make the same error